# Why seq in Haskell has to have special rule for bottom?

Tags: haskell

Haskell Report 2010 says that `seq` "weakens Haskell’s parametricity properties", as "⊥ is not the same as \x -> ⊥, since seq can be used to distinguish them" [1].

It seems that it happens exactly because of an explicit rule:

```hs
seq ⊥ b  =  ⊥
```

I was wondering why this special case was introduced?
There must be a reason why

```hs
seq a b  =  b
```

would not be enough, and `seq` needs a more complicated definition with that special case:

```hs
seq ⊥ b  =  ⊥
seq a b  =  b, if a ≠ ⊥
```

[1] https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1260006.2

---

[edit]  It clarify the question, here is another angle on it.
Why can not `seq` be defined like this:

```hs
seq :: a -> b -> b
seq a b  =  b
```

> With a rule that `seq` is a special function that would evaluate its first argument "as much as possible".  If evaluation results in HNF, then the argument is completely evaluated.  If it would result in an exception or a bottom value, those are stored and would be thrown or returned whenever first argument would actually be used in evaluation of the second argument.

It is a bit lame, but I think that should make my questions a bit more clear.  It is not about how `seq` works.  It is about the intentions of the current design.

Maybe there are some obvious reasons, from the implementation standpoint.  Or maybe it would have some consequences, like inability to provide some useful properties that are currently based on the `seq` been defined with that special case for bottom.
Or maybe there are some other connections that I am not aware of.
This is what I am quirious about :)

Comment: maybe I'm totally stupid here but the first just states the fact that seq is strict in the first argument and that's the point in using seq in the first place (it evaluates a to HNF)

Comment: (As an aside, it actually seems to be an open question whether `⊥` needs to be distinguishable from `\x -> ⊥`.  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19165/is-eta-equivalence-for-functions-compatiable-with-haskells-seq-operation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer above contains a discussion that eventually allowed me to understand what was I missing.  I think that the following is the gist of it.

Proposed definition would require solution to the halting problem, if we limit ourselves to one thread only.  ⊥ means 3 different things: exceptions, errors and non-termination.  First two could be dealt with, but the third on is impossible to solve in a general case.

It might be possible to provide an implementation that would use an additional thread to run evaluation of `a`.  But it looks like a much more complicated solution, possibly, with its own pitfalls.

Answer (score 15):

The whole point of `seq x y` is to *evaluate* `x` and then return `y`. Haskell is lazy, so a definition such as

```
seq x y = y
```

won't do, since `x` is left unevaluated. If we knew `x :: Int` we could write

```
seq x y = case x of
          0 -> y
          _ -> y
```

forcing `x` to be evaluated. We can play the same trick for lists, trees, etc. with a significant exception: *functions*. If `x` is a function, we can not `case` over it (trivial patterns aside, which do no force evaluation). Functions are only evaluated on call, so we might attempt

```
seq x y = case x 12 of -- let's pretend it's an Int->Int function
          0 -> y
          _ -> y
```

this will force the evaluation of `x` (good!), but will also evaluate `x 12` (bad!).

It turns out that we know that writing `seq` in the lambda-calculus is actually *impossible*: theory formalizes the intuition around "we cannot force a function unless we apply, and if we apply we are also forcing the result".

So, in Haskell, `seq` was added as a primitive operation, not definable in terms of everything else. The implementation of `seq` is strict on its first argument, even if there's no need to evaluate it to return the second.

Since `seq` does something outside the lambda-calculus, it breaks a few things in the theory, such as parametricity, but this loss is not so large to ruin the whole language, which still enjoys many of the nice theoretical properties of the lambda calculus.

Historically, if my memory serves me right, early Haskell was about to include a class for `seq`:

```
 class Seq a where
    seq :: a -> b -> b
```

and this class was instantianted on every type *but functions*, so that parametricity was preserved as well. Later, it was decided that it was not practical to add all the `Seq a` constraints in the code, since a single use of `seq` would have required to add a large number of constraints around. So, `seq` was made into a primitive, at the cost of breaking the theory a bit.

Comment: A class would require instantiations for any new types user could have added, would it not?  I am still new to Haskell, so I might be missing something here...
In short, you are saying that the first rule is there to allow "class based" implementation?  Because if not, and `seq` is "a primitive operation, not definable in terms of everything else", I still do not see a point of the first rule.

Comment: @IlyaBobyr No, `seq` was made into a primitive that does not require type classes. Without the first rule `seq` is just `flip const`, which is not the same. Try e.g. `seq (error "evaluated!") 42` and `flip const (error "evaluated!") 42`. Or replace the error with a computation requiring a very long time.

Comment: I understand what `seq` does.  I do not understand why the special case is needed.  If it is "magic" function, why could not it be required, for example, to evaluate its first argument "as much as possible".  If it would throw an exception, stop just before that.  If it would be bottom, store bottom and carry on with the second argument.  And then, whenever the second argument would actually use the first one - only then either throw an exception, return bottom or return the HNF that was calculated.  Are there any implementation difficulties with this approach?  Or theoretical?

Comment: I do not think that `flip const` is the same.  There are no requirements on evaluation of the arguments.  They would still be stored in the thunk form.

Comment: @IlyaBobyr If seq is defined without the first rule then we have `seq = \x y -> y = flip cost`. On alternative magic functions: stopping just before an exception could be done, theoretically. You can not however test for bottom, since we can't solve the halting problem (at most we can test for the "exceptional" bottoms such as undefined or error).

Comment: @IlyaBobyr I think that you might be confused by the (indeed confusing) convention of using bottom to represent both non termination (as in `let f x = f (x+1) in f 4`) and exceptions/errors (`error "urk"`). The first kind can not be handled specially, the only thing we can do is to fully evaluate an argument, and let `seq` diverge in that case, so `seq bottom _ = bottom`. The second kind is not a "real" bottom, bot an exception, and could indeed be handled specially.

Comment: `inline` is defined as `inline x = x`, yet it does not make it the same as some `f x = x`.  `seq` is magic with or without the first rule.  The difference is what the magic rules are.  So I do not understand what is the meaning of saying `seq = \x y -> y = flip cost`.  Am I missing something?  OTOH, saying that the first rule allows implementations not to solve the halting problem would be quite a good argument, if you ask me :)
I think that you are right that I was confused by that convention.
Exceptions could still be handled in a special manner.  Another questions is if they should be.

Comment: While people are upvoting this answer, I think that the answer to my original question would be: "the first rule allows implementations not to solve the halting problem".  Should I add it as a new answer and mark it as accepted, or will you add it and then I will mark it?  Or this is not how it should be done? :)

Comment: @IlyaBobyr I believe that the first rule of seq is meant to specify the required "magic", in a denotational rather than operational flavor. If you take only the second rule, but add the "magic" then it's fine. My comments above considered seq defined using the second rule only, without any magic attached to it.

Comment: @IlyaBobyr The first rule is just a means to express "there is a magical evaluation of the 1st arg even if it is not needed", so that `seq  /=  \x y -> y = flip const`. without the first rule, i.e. without any magic, `seq  =  \x y -> y = flip const`. You propose different behaviour for seq -- exceptions, errors could be done; even non-termination could be dealt with by calculating it in a separate thread with progressively increasing timeout. Why wasn't it done this way? Perhaps the *simplest* thing was chosen.